# Delegate method shouldBeginSignUp NOT CALLED - Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am using the `PFSignUpViewController` but the `shouldBeginSignUp` delegate method is never called. I want to check the username (length, ...) **before** it is signed up. Therefor this method must work... 
Here is my code:

```
class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

var logInViewController: PFLogInViewController! = LoginViewController()
var signUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController! = SignUpViewController()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.logInViewController.delegate = self         
    self.signUpViewController.delegate = self

    self.logInViewController.signUpController = self.signUpViewController
}


func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, shouldBeginSignUp info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    print("shouldBeginSignUp...") // not called...

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First question,
I believed that you need to provide data into the dictionary of that function, then you check if username and password are correct then either return true or false

The second part if you want to check the length of both password / username

**let's assume you have two IBOutlet, where one is for username and the other one for password**

so you will do something like that

```
     if password.characters.count > 6 {// do whatever you want} 
     if username.characters.count > 6  {// do whatever you want}
```

what if you want to check if the IBOutlet is empty

```
   if username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty
```

Comment: Yes for sure... But this logic shout be executed in the shouldBeginSignUp method witch is not called!

Comment: I believed you need to do something check the username and password in order for this function to work